# codeAnyWhere github command git status

Tags: git, github, command-line, codeanywhere

I am very new to the github and codeAnyWhere. I started new project and connented my exciting repo to codeAnywhere and made a few changes in the project fold and typed in git status in the ssh commond window. The screen dose not look right as all text are white and the file that I made changes to was supposed to be highlighted in red but it is in white text and there are "*" at the beginning of each line.
what I did wrong, anyone has had this problem before.

thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your output from `git status` looks completely typical to me; I see nothing wrong here.

Comment: I just edit my question and added a second pic of my git bash screen, you see it is colored in red and green. So in codeAnyWhere, my screen output is different to git bash and it is normal>

Comment: Again, nothing wrong at all.  Files not yet staged for commit show up in red, and staged files show up in green.  Anything else?

Comment: I just watched someone's tutorial on youtube about using github on codeAnyWhere and his screen is different to mine but the video was recorded in 2016. I guess there are many updates have been made to codeAnyWhere since 2016.

Comment: Rather than worrying about how the output of `git status` _looks_, instead focus on what it _says_.  Do you see any actual information which looks wrong to you?  I don't see any obvious problems.

Comment: yes,you're right.thanks

Comment: When your local Git is really broken, believe me, you'll know it, because nothing will be working.

Answer (score 0):

for a colored output check out [git config's](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) "Colors in Git" section.